# Is it possible to have a clock that counts up in days?

Tags: python-3.1

Recently I've been working on a file for python-3.1 and I was wondering if there is a way to have a clock that counts up in days, for example, if the set day was the 10th of July 2016 the screen would display the number 12 if the file was opened on the 22nd of July 2016

Comment: The answer to your question is "Yes."

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: Questions like this aren't appropriate for this website. You need to share the code you've written so far and the specific issue you need help with.

Comment: I haven't written any code yet as I don't know where to start and I have explained to the best of my ability what I need help with.